# Factory reset a Panasonic Lumix DMC-CM1 - can't start settings to enable USB debugging

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, settings, factory-reset

A recent update to the Panasonic Lumix DMC-CM1 seems to have broken something fundamental.

System apps will load but the screen will stay blank. e.g. `Settings` loads up and shows the header with 'Settings' but the rest of the screen is white. I have left it 30 mins and it stays that way. It frequently stalls and has to be rebooted, sometimes you see `Launcher3/Settings/etc is not responding`, neither `wait` nor `close` help. Same in safe mode. I have turned on airplane mode, turned off basically everything I can, removed SD card and SIM etc. Still the same. `Google Play` wont load so I can't load any apps that might help.

Unfortunately that means I can't turn on `Enable USB Debugging`, and so I am limited in my options. It seems like the only options are the following:

- Using a 'secret code': `*#06#` works (shows IMEI num) but nothing else seems to, though I did find an info window in the background one time (I think must have been `*#*#4636#*#*`). I am going off a list of codes [I found here.](https://www.androidprotips.com/secret-codes-panasonic-lumix-dmc-cm1/)
- Using Recovery Mode: There seem to be a lot of different ideas on how to get into recovery on this phone, but none of them work for me. [It seems like it's possible to get into a fastboot mode](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=71685271&postcount=75) and from there you can do `adb reboot recovery` **but only if `Enable USB Debugging` is on**! :/

Is there anything else I can do?  I am not even sure what version of Android is on it, perhaps 4.4

Comment: the linked post descripes how to enter fastboot mode without usb-debugging. however, you can not boot straight into recovery from fastboot mode. but you can try to unlock bootloader for factory reset (fastboot boot recovery.img from pc will also work after this)

Comment: Recent update? Android version 5.0.2 with android security patch level 2015-12-01 is the latest I can get. That last updated happened maybe 3 year ago.